# Need to filter a datatable on 2 columns which creates a unique combination?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, filtering

I have a data table with 5 columns, I need to find the max date per 2 column unique combination.

Looking for guidance, on how to accomplish, so haven't tried anything yet. Would I concatenate the 2 column values and use that as my unique value to pull the max records? This is where I'm lost on how to best accomplish this task

Here is a simple data table with the columns in question

```
Column 1 Column 2 Column 3 Column 4 Column 5
     2   4/25/2019      25          
     2   3/25/2019      26          
     2   2/15/2019      25

Column 1 Column 2 Column 3 Column 4 Column 5
     2   4/25/2019       25         
     2   3/25/2019       26
```

If I ran my filter against these 3 records I would expect to receive back 2 records like above.
Reason is I need the `Column 1` and `Column 3` to be unique and then I only want the one with the max date.

Comment: so you only care about these 3 columns why have the other two columns listed in the example

Comment: @jdweng -- I can't imagine why you would need a pivot for this question.  Seems like spam to me.

Comment: My example is a small sample, my datatable has 18 columns, there are only 3 columns i need in order to identify which record i need and thats the reason for the small truncated sample.. above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i assume you are looking for this:

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("Col2", typeof(DateTime));
    dt.Columns.Add("Col3", typeof(int));

    dt.Rows.Add(2, DateTime.Parse("2/15/2019"), 25);
    dt.Rows.Add(2, DateTime.Parse("5/25/2019"), 25);
    dt.Rows.Add(2, DateTime.Parse("3/25/2019"), 26);

    dt.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => new {col1 = r.Field<int>("Col1"), col2 = r.Field<int>("Col3")} )
    .Select(g =>
        g.Select(s=> s).OrderByDescending(o=>o.Field<DateTime>("Col2")).FirstOrDefault()
    );
```

Comment: So in your example, would i get back the 2 records out of the 3?   dt.Rows.Add(2, DateTime.Parse("5/25/2019"), 25);
    dt.Rows.Add(2, DateTime.Parse("3/25/2019"), 26);

Comment: Yes, get linqpad and test it

Comment: Preliminary validation looks to be correct and as expected. Waiting for the business user to respond with their own validation, but i think it works.. we will see as i open up the query to work with thousands of rows instead of just a few hundred. thank you all

Comment: for performance you might look in to [Parallelizm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ to achieve what you're after:

```cs
// foos.GroupBy(c => c.Number)
    .Select(c => c.OrderByDescending(b => b.Date).Take(1))
    .SelectMany(c => c).ToList();

// as pointed out by @Flater, using `Take(1)` will return an `IEnumerable<T>`
//  which requires unnecessary flattening through `SelectMany()`.
// instead, use .First() to take off the top of the ordered collection
foos.GroupBy(c => c.Number)
    .Select(c => c.OrderByDescending(b => b.Date).First());
```

This will group each item by a property called `Number`, which is your `Column3`. Then it will take the item with the highest date from each group, then flatten it back down to a list of your entity type.

Comment: Part of the question is how to use two number to get the unique group

Comment: Doing a `Take(1)` and then flattening the list can be simplified by simply calling `First()` and then you don't need to flatten the list. (note: `FirstOrDefault` isn't particularly necessary since you know for a fact that grouped lists always contain at least one item, otherwise the group wouldn't exist)

Comment: I will try the suggestions and research on these methods some more.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

As @mariocatch said you can use group by -- you can create a unique key multiple columns using this technique:

```
group x by new { x.Column1, x.Column3 }
```

or

```
GroupBy(x => new { x.Column1, x.Column3 })
```

Your result would look something like this:

```
foos.GroupBy(x => new { x.Column1, x.Column3 })
   .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Date).First()
```

Comment: The Group is creating a PIVOT Table.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, ill try these out and see what happens.. LINQ is new to me and wasnt sure if that was the route to go with this request, ill post back which my results or issues if any

Comment: @jdweng - how can it be creating a pivot table?  It is not doing anything to an SQL database.  This is a question about using Linq a C# language element.

Comment: The first step in creating a pivot table is a group.  The table is just how you display the group results.